# Disable SharePoint mobile view for a specific page only for example main.aspx

Tags: 2013

I understand SharePoint 2013 automatically points to mobile view when viewing a site from a mobile device.  However I would like to disable mobile view for a specific page only while maintaining the mobile view for other pages.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution I can come up with that does not include fondeling with 3rd party software or snooping in the web.config file would be to insert either a usercontrol or some javascript on the page which changes the `/?mobile=1` to `/?mobile=0`.

Comment: There are mobile phones that do not have Javascript capabilities, though.

Comment: @dzookatz True. Also why I suggested usercontrol as an option

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Inbound Rule URL to the URL of your specific page. Please see [this](http://www.getsharepoint.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=115) tutorial on details.

Setting the `isMobileDevice` property to `false` for the specific page should also work, assuming that the page has it. Seen [here](http://joranmarkx.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/how-to-disable-mobile-view-in-sharepoint-2010/) and [here](http://www.khamis.net/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=6c8a23d1-47ea-47e5-b56f-2bc57cb95b93&ID=51&Web=d64cd8b3-a3f4-40d8-8d93-6aa6dc82fcda).

**EDIT:**

There is a `MobileView` property, which, when set to `false`, disables the mobile view of the page. Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414170%28v=office.14%29.aspx). This can easily be edited with SP Designer.